# Eslint prettier false positives in React - serviceWorker.ts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, babeljs, eslint

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFtC4.png)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbCVa.png)

EsLint prettier creates false positives error messages in the widget dashboard directory. Specifically from the serviceWorker.ts file. Running lint does not throw any error, where the error only shows in the console after bundling. Please advice, thank you kindly.

```
"dependencies": {
"@babel/core": "7.10.3",
"@babel/preset-env": "7.10.3",
"@babel/preset-react": "7.10.1",
"@svgr/webpack": "4.3.3",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
"@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
"@types/jest": "^24.0.0",
"@types/node": "^12.0.0",
"@types/react": "^16.9.0",
"@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "2.10.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "2.10.0",
"babel-eslint": "10.0.3",
"babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
"babel-loader": "8.1.0",
"babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.3.6",
"babel-preset-react-app": "^9.1.2",
"camelcase": "^5.3.1",
"case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.3.0",
"css-loader": "3.4.2",
"dotenv": "8.2.0",
"dotenv-expand": "5.1.0",
"eslint": "6.7.2",
"eslint-config-prettier": "6.7.0",
"eslint-config-react-app": "^5.2.1",
"eslint-loader": "3.0.3",
"eslint-plugin-flowtype": "4.6.0",
"eslint-plugin-fp": "2.3.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "2.18.2",
"eslint-plugin-import-helpers": "^1.0.2",
"eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "18.4.1",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.2.3",
"eslint-plugin-prettier": "3.1.0",
"eslint-plugin-react": "7.19.0",
"eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.6.1",
"eslint-plugin-sonarjs": "0.5.0",
"eslint-plugin-unicorn": "10.0.0",
"file-loader": "4.3.0",
"fs-extra": "^8.1.0",
"html-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-beta.11",
"identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
"jest": "24.9.0",
"jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen": "1.0.1",
"jest-resolve": "24.9.0",
"jest-watch-typeahead": "0.4.2",
"mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.9.0",
"optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.3",
"pnp-webpack-plugin": "1.6.4",
"postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "4.1.0",
"postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
"postcss-normalize": "8.0.1",
"postcss-preset-env": "6.7.0",
"postcss-safe-parser": "4.0.1",
"prettier": "1.19.1",
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.6",
"react-dev-utils": "^10.2.1",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1",
"resolve": "1.15.0",
"resolve-url-loader": "3.1.1",
"sass-loader": "8.0.2",
"semver": "6.3.0",
"style-loader": "0.23.1",
"terser-webpack-plugin": "2.3.5",
"ts-pnp": "1.1.6",
"typescript": "3.7.2",
"url-loader": "2.3.0",
"webpack": "4.42.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "3.10.3",
"webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.2.0",
"workbox-webpack-plugin": "4.3.1"
```

},

- .babelrc

  {
  "presets": [
  "react-app",
  "@babel/preset-env",
  "@babel/preset-react"
  ]
  }
- Error log

> ./source/serviceWorker.ts   Line 11:29:   Insert `⏎··`
> prettier/prettier   Line 12:1:    Insert `··`
> prettier/prettier   Line 13:1:    Replace
> `window.location.hostname.match(/^127(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)){3}$/));`
> with
> `····window.location.hostname.match(/^127(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)){3}$/),⏎)`
> prettier/prettier   Line 17:76:   Delete `;`
> prettier/prettier   Line 23:13:   Delete `;`
> prettier/prettier   Line 27:66:   Delete `;`
> prettier/prettier   Line 31:47:   Delete `;`
> prettier/prettier   Line 35:23:   Replace
> `"This·web·app·is·being·served·cache-first·by·a·service·"·+·"worker.·To·learn·more,·visit·`[here][3]`);`
> with
> `⏎············"This·web·app·is·being·served·cache-first·by·a·service·"·+⏎··············"worker.·To·learn·more,·visit·[here][3],⏎··········)`
> prettier/prettier   Line 36:11:   Delete `;`
> prettier/prettier   Line 39:39:   Delete `;`
> prettier/prettier   Line 41:7:    Delete `;`
> prettier/prettier   Line 46:26:   Replace `.register(swUrl)` with
> `⏎····.register(swUrl)⏎····`
> prettier/prettier   Line 47:5:    Insert `··`
> prettier/prettier   Line 48:1:    Replace
> `······const·installingWorker·=·registration.installing;` with
> `········const·installingWorker·=·registration.installing`
> prettier/prettier   Line 50:7:    Insert `··`
> prettier/prettier   Line 51:1:    Replace `········return;` with
> `··········return`
> prettier/prettier   Line 52:1:    Insert `··`
> prettier/prettier   Line 54:1:    Replace `······` with `········`
> prettier/prettier   Line 55:1:    Insert `··`
> prettier/prettier   Line 56:1:    Replace `··········` with
> `············`
> prettier/prettier   Line 57:1:    Insert `··`
> prettier/prettier   Line 58:1:    Insert `··`
> prettier/prettier   Line 59:13:   Insert `··`
> prettier/prettier   Line 60:1:    Replace
> `············console.log("New·content·is·available·and·will·be·used·when·all·"·+·"tabs·for·this·page·are·closed.);`
> with
> `··············console.log(⏎················"New·content·is·available·and·will·be·used·when·all·"·+⏎··················"tabs·for·this·page·are·closed.",⏎··············)`
> prettier/prettier   Line 62:1:    Insert `··`
> prettier/prettier   Line 63:1:    Replace
> `··············config.onUpdate(registration);` with
> `················config.onUpdate(registration)`
> prettier/prettier   Line 64:1:    Insert `··`
> prettier/prettier   Line 65:1:    Replace `··········` with
> `············`
> prettier/prettier   Line 66:1:    Insert `··`
> prettier/prettier   Line 67:1:    Insert `··`
> prettier/prettier   Line 68:13:   Insert `··`
> prettier/prettier   Line 69:1:    Replace
> `············console.log("Content·is·cached·for·offline·use.");` with
> `··············console.log("Content·is·cached·for·offline·use.")`
> prettier/prettier   Line 71:1:    Insert `··`
> prettier/prettier   Line 72:15:   Replace
> `config.onSuccess(registration);` with
> `··config.onSuccess(registration)`
> prettier/prettier   Line 73:1:    Insert `··`
> prettier/prettier   Line 74:11:   Insert `··`
> prettier/prettier   Line 75:1:    Insert `··`
> prettier/prettier   Line 76:7:    Replace `};` with `··}`
> prettier/prettier   Line 77:1:    Replace `····};` with `······}`
> prettier/prettier   Line 78:1:    Replace `··})` with `····})⏎····`
> prettier/prettier   Line 79:5:    Replace
> `console.error("Error·during·service·worker·registration:",·error);`
> with
> `··console.error("Error·during·service·worker·registration:",·error)`
> prettier/prettier   Line 80:1:    Replace `··});` with `····})`
> prettier/prettier   Line 87:33:   Insert `,`
> prettier/prettier   Line 88:6:    Insert `,`
> prettier/prettier   Line 89:5:    Insert `⏎····`
> prettier/prettier   Line 90:1:    Insert `··`
> prettier/prettier   Line 91:1:    Replace
> `····const·contentType·=·response.headers.get("content-type");` with
> `······const·contentType·=·response.headers.get("content-type")`
> prettier/prettier   Line 93:1:    Replace
> `····if·(response.status·===·404·||·contentType·!=·null·&&·!contentType.includes("javascript"`
> with
> `······if·(response.status·===·404·||·(contentType·!=·null·&&·!contentType.includes("javascript")`                                                                                                                                                      prettier/prettier   Line 94:7:    Insert `··`
> prettier/prettier   Line 95:1:    Insert `··`
> prettier/prettier   Line 96:9:    Insert `··`
> prettier/prettier   Line 97:11:   Replace `window.location.reload();`
> with `··window.location.reload()`
> prettier/prettier   Line 98:1:    Replace `········});` with
> `··········})`
> prettier/prettier   Line 99:7:    Replace `});` with `··})`
> prettier/prettier   Line 100:1:   Insert `··`
> prettier/prettier   Line 101:1:   Insert `··`
> prettier/prettier   Line 102:1:   Replace
> `······registerValidSW(swUrl,·config);` with
> `········registerValidSW(swUrl,·config)`
> prettier/prettier   Line 103:1:   Insert `··`
> prettier/prettier   Line 104:1:   Replace `··})` with `····})⏎····`
> prettier/prettier   Line 105:1:   Replace
> `····console.log("No·internet·connection·found.·App·is·running·in·offline·mode.");`
> with
> `······console.log("No·internet·connection·found.·App·is·running·in·offline·mode.")`
> prettier/prettier   Line 106:3:   Replace `});` with `··})`
> prettier/prettier   Line 111:34:  Insert `⏎······`
> prettier/prettier   Line 112:1:   Replace
> `······registration.unregister();` with
> `········registration.unregister()`
> prettier/prettier   Line 113:1:   Replace `····})` with
> `······})⏎······`
> prettier/prettier   Line 114:1:   Replace
> `······console.error(error.message);` with
> `········console.error(error.message)`
> prettier/prettier

Comment: We will need more information to be able to help. Just a message saying it failed to compile is of no help.

Comment: @CerebralFart I added the error log